# Why don't secp256k1 use a prime order subgroup?

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-theory

Using a `prime order subgroup` prevents mounting a `Pohlig–Hellman` algorithm attack. Meanwhile, secp256k1 doesn't use a `prime order subgroup`.

- What is the idea behind not using a prime order subgroup?
- How does it prevent the `Pohlig–Hellman` attack?

Comment: You are mistaken. The ‘secp256k1’ curve defines a group of prime order, thus the whole group can be considered a prime order subgroup. See [page 9 of the SEC 2 document](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1)

Comment: I've assumed they know that it is prime order, however, it might not be clear that the only subgroups are the trivial subgroups due to the Lagrange Theorem. That was the whole point of my answer. Now, included the definition of Secp256k1 to make it more clear.

Comment: Problems with the question: 1) secp256k1 is a prime order subgroup, of itself. 2) In "How does it prevent the Pohlig–Hellman attack" it's unclear if "it" refers to secp256k1, "using a prime order subgroup", or "not using a prime order subgroup".

Answer (score 1):

**A little Introduction to Secp256k1;**

[Secp256k1](http://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#page9) is a Koblitz curve **with a prime order** i.e. the number of points on the curve together with the point at infinity is prime.

`n = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141`
and cofactor $h= 1$

Cofactor $h=1$ also implies that the curve has prime order.

> **1. Why doesn't secp256k1 use a prime order subgroup?**

There is a theorem of [Lagrange in Group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory))

- **Theorem** :  If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, then $\left|G\right|=\left[G:H\right]\cdot \left|H\right|.$

Namely, any order of a subgroup of a group must divide the group's order. Since the prime curves have prime order the only possible orders are the trivial ones; The group formed by the multiplicative identity and the whole group with orders 1 and n, respectively.

Note that $\mathbb{Z^*_p}$ is not a prime order multiplicative group. Elliptic curves provide us with some of the prime order groups.

You can't because the curve order of Secp256k1 is prime and by Lagrange's Theorem, there aren't such subgroups.

One needs non-prime orders to find smaller subgroups. Non-primes is necessary but not sufficient i.e. The reverse of the Lagrange theorem doesn't hold. There are groups that have a divisor of the order, however, there is no such subgroup of that order. The famous example is the $A_4$ (the alternating group of degree 4) with 12 elements yet it has no subgroups of order $4$

> **2. How does it prevent Pohlig–Hellman attack**

If we look at the Pohlig–Hellman algorithm in Wikipedia;

- In group theory, the Pohlig–Hellman algorithm, sometimes credited as the Silver–Pohlig–Hellman algorithm, is a special-purpose algorithm for computing discrete logarithms in a finite abelian group whose order is a smooth integer.

This includes an implicit definition of a smooth integer; a $n$-smooth integer is a number whose prime factor is less than or equal to $n$.

Pohlig–Hellman algorithm benefits the factors of the group's order, **if there are no factors** then the complexity is $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ and turns into Baby-Step-Giant-Step algorithm where Pollard's $\rho$ much better since it has constant space requirement.

> **3. What are the idea behind not using a prime order subgroup?**

One cannot use subgroups with prime curves. There are differences in the applications of prime curves $h=1$ and non-prime curves $h> 1$, namely the fast Montgomery Ladder in Montgomery curves;

1. 1987, Montgomery introduced the Montgomery ladder for [the speed-up EC factorings](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7/).

   To use the Montgomery Ladder, the curve has a co-factor $h$ must be $4$ or a multiple of it ($h = \#E(k)/n$ with large prime $p|n$). The Curve25519 has co-factor $8$ and Ed448 has $4$.
2. 2002, Éric Brier & Marc Joye generalized the ladder for the whole general Weierstraß form of elliptic curves. This is slower compared to Montgomery.
3. 2006, [this ladder is used in ECDH](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf) (Curve25519: new Diffie-Hellman speed records) since it has side-channel resistance by its design.

   Montgomery had no such consideration since side-channel [appeared in 1999 by Kocker et al.](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s13389-011-0006-y.pdf)